# Reading from void pointer -- reinterpret_cast okay?

Tags: c++

I have been debugging my code for some time now and I need a sanity check that reinterpret_cast is not the issue. Its been a while since I have used C/C++ and I may forgetting the basics.

In my function, I have been given some amount of generic data `void *data` From other parameters passed in, I know the size of the data and where certain types are offset'ed. For example, `data` has a size of 12 bytes: first 4 bytes are an int, the next 4 bytes are chars, and the last 4 bytes are ints.

Question:
How would I grab each peace of data (int, char, char, char, char, int) from data? I have, so far, been using `reinterpret_cast` and it works! However can such a instance come up where my values (memFirst4, memA, memB, etc.) are not what I expected because I am using reinterpret_cast?

```
void *data = malloc((sizeof(int)*3)); // 12 bytes .. my compiler has ints as 4 bytes
int first4 = 8075;
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
char c = 'c';
char d = 'd';
int last4 = 981;
memcpy(data,&first4,sizeof(int)); // copy first4 into memory
memcpy(data+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*1,&a,sizeof(char)); // copy char a into memory
memcpy(data+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*2,&b,sizeof(char)); // copy char b into memory
memcpy(data+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*3,&c,sizeof(char)); // copy char c into memory
memcpy(data+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*4,&d,sizeof(char)); // copy char d into memory
memcpy(data+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*4+sizeof(int),&last4,sizeof(int)); // copy last4 into memory

int memFirst4 = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(data);
char memA = *reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*1);
char memB = *reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*2);
char memC = *reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*3);
char memD = *reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*4);
int memLast4 = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(data+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*4+sizeof(int));
free(data);
```

Comment: C/C++ is not a language, and `reinterpret_cast` is not C, so "C and/or C++" doesn't apply. Removing the C tag.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is the right tool. It just takes a pointer and allows you to dereference it as if it was the type you passed. Where do you expect problems (other than that `int` may not always be 4 bytes)?

Comment: Ah, and you got the last cast wrong, the additional `sizeof(int)` is too much.

Comment: @filmor I am pretty sure the last cast needs the additional `sizeof(int)`. I ran this code and it checks out, it does print the value 981. If I remove it, it prints out 100, which is the ASCII value of 'd.'

Comment: All but the first offsets are wrong.

Comment: @stefaanv can you explain a bit? Are you saying that the first `memcpy` line is okay, but all the rest are wrong? Essentially the rest of the `memcpy` lines are spilling into memory that I have not allocated via `malloc`?

Comment: @Adam: all the char's are written and read with 1 off, the last int is written to after the allocated buffer.

Comment: @Adam Grab some paper, draw 12 boxes and for each call check which box the pointer points at. It will always have to point to the *start* of the memory you want to write to or read from.

Comment: Both stefaanv and filmor thank you, very much! I may have have narrowed down the issue in my code as it was my understanding of offsets, which both of you have cleared up (including drawing 12 boxes :-) ). Loading up a hex editor, I think I see some overlap and empty blocks which. Both of you have put me on the right track to debug this issue. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will work, but is pretty risky (easy to make mistake, copy one byte less or more). Therefore, I would recomment a union:

```
#pragma pack(1)
union myData
{ 
  char data[12];
  struct fields 
    { 
      uint8_t i[4];
      char c[4];
      uint8_t i2[4];
    } u_fields;
}
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Union allows you to read the same chunk of memory as different types (in this case using char[12] data and fields struct).

[Have a look here for more info](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/)

Comment: Will that work? Normally, `struct`s are padded, is that not done inside of `union`s? Also, he wants `int`, not `uint8_t[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use reinterpret_cast.Casting some pointer from void* is not allowed using reinterpret_cast.

When you want to cast from void* to something else, you can use static_cast. But remember converting from one type to another (not the same) type using void* in between will yield to an unspecified pointer value.

Comment: I don't think this is true anymore for C++11. Also, no compiler I used ever checked this for C++03 and `p == reinterpret_cast<type*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(p))` was always guaranteed by the standard.